# transferring IPv4 /32 to another datacenter

Tags: routing, ipv4

We are planning to migrate one set of IPv4 /32 series owned by us, from one dedicated server provider to another provider. Is it necessary to have permission to release the IP series from previous provider before advertising from the new server provider?

Comment: Your problem is that the longest provider-independent addressing is `/24`. The `/32` addresses you have are assigned to your current ISP by the RIR, and it would need to release the entire `/24` of a single address to the new ISP, and that really will not happen.

Comment: This all sounds odd. Are you sure you actually OWN an address space? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you own the IP space, you can move it wherever you want.  But as @ronmaupin points out, you can't advertise /32's to the Internet.  The smallest subnet that will be advertised is /24.

Answer (score 3):

When you "buy" a public IP, the provider is lending it to you, to have IPs under your administration you need to become an ASN, I suggest you read your contract.

Comment: These are owned by us from APNIC.